# Include CSS,javascript file in Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii

How to include a Javascript or CSS file in Yii Framework?

I want to create a page on my site that has a little Javascript application running, so I want to include `.js` and `.css` files in a specific view.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php  
  $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
  $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
  $cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/yourcss.css');
?>
```

Comment: should I call this from the controller of from the view?

Comment: You should call this from a view

Comment: @user1077220 It makes no difference.

Comment: CSS and JS registrations are relate to view. So more logically to call it from a view.

Comment: although you had better use an extended ClientScript component that combine and minify css and js like https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/yii-EClientScript

Comment: You can do it in one line , {Yii::app()->request->baseUrl}/js/include.js

Comment: should i have to add this in every view?

Comment: This should be added once per page (no matter in which view you will add above snippet)

Comment: Note you can specify the location you want your css/js to be registered. That is you can specify for it to be after title (ideal for css), at the bottom or after the page is ready Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
        Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/assets/plugins/datatable/dataTables.editor.bootstrap.js', CClientScript::POS_END);

Answer (score 47):

You can do so by adding

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/your/script');
```

Answer (score 34):

I liked to answer this question.

Their are many places where we have css & javascript files, like in css folder which is outside the protected folder, css & js files of extension & widgets which we need to include externally sometime when use ajax a lot, js & css files of core framework which also we need to include externally sometime. So their are some ways to do this.

**Include core js files of framework like jquery.js, jquery.ui.js**

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');     
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui'); 
?>
```

**Include files from css folder outside of protected folder.**

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/example.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/example.js');
?>
```

**Include css & js files from extension or widgets.**

Here fancybox is an extension which is placed under protected folder.
Files we including has path : **/protected/extensions/fancybox/assets/**

```
<?php
// Fancybox stuff.
$assetUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.fancybox.assets'));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($assetUrl.'/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js'); 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($assetUrl.'/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js'); 
?>
```

**Also we can include core framework files:**
Example : I am including CListView js file.

```
<?php
$baseScriptUrl=Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('zii.widgets.assets'));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseScriptUrl.'/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js',CClientScript::POS_END);  
?>
```

- We need to include js files of zii widgets or extension externally sometimes when we use them in rendered view which are received from ajax call, because loading each time new ajax file create conflict in calling js functions.

For more detail [Look at my blog article](http://www.waytoblogger.com/blog/technical/yii/register-js-css-files-in-yii-framework/)

Answer (score 21):

Easy in your conf/main.php. This is my example with bootstrap. You can see that [here](https://github.com/jknito/kTemplate/blob/master/protected/config/main.php)

```
'components'=>array(
    'clientScript' => array(
        'scriptMap' => array(
            'jquery.js'=>false,  //disable default implementation of jquery
            'jquery.min.js'=>false,  //desable any others default implementation
            'core.css'=>false, //disable
            'styles.css'=>false,  //disable
            'pager.css'=>false,   //disable
            'default.css'=>false,  //disable
        ),
        'packages'=>array(
            'jquery'=>array(                             // set the new jquery
                'baseUrl'=>'bootstrap/',
                'js'=>array('js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'),
            ),
            'bootstrap'=>array(                       //set others js libraries
                'baseUrl'=>'bootstrap/',
                'js'=>array('js/bootstrap.min.js'),
                'css'=>array(                        // and css
                    'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                    'css/custom.css',
                    'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css',
                ),
                'depends'=>array('jquery'),         // cause load jquery before load this.
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: So how would you then "call" the javascript where you need it to be implemented ?

Comment: you can use this way:

  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('bootstrap');

Answer (score 7):

In the view, add the following:

```
<?php  
  $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
  $cs->registerScriptFile('/js/yourscript.js', CClientScript::POS_END);
  $cs->registerCssFile('/css/yourcss.css');
?>
```

Please notice the second parameter when you register the js file, it's the position of your script, when you set it CClientScript::POS_END, you let the HTML renders before the javascript is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

Do somthing like this by adding these line to your view files;

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/your/javascript/file');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/css/file');
```

Answer (score 6):

To include JS and CSS files in a specific view you can do it via controller by passing the parameters `false, true`, which will include the CSS and JS for, e.g.:

```
$this->renderPartial(
    'yourviewname',
    array(
        'model' => $model,
        false,
        true
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many methods that we can [include javascript, css into your Yii App](http://www.codexamples.com/98/how-to-include-javascript-css-in-yii/). Today I will demonstrate three simple and helpul methods.

A simple way to add js, css by editing config/main.php

```
// application components
  'components'=>array(
         // ...
        'clientScript'=>array(
            'packages'=>array(
                'jquery'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
                )
            ),
        ),
        // ...
  ),
```

Using getClientScript

Usually, We add in block of code into Controller or layout of your theme

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/yourcss.css');
```

Or shorter:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/your/javascript/file',CClientScript::POS_END);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/css/file');
```

Include core js files

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');     
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
```

Faster Yii API Document: http://yii.codexamples.com/

Comment: @Christian this is not a forum, and you are encouraged to add on to questions if you are contributing **new** AND **useful** information.

Comment: @Truongnq If I place this block `$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/yourcss.css');` in the Controller, where do I assign `$cs` after? Moreover, in my `actionView` in my Controller I have this line `$this -> render('view', array('model' => $this -> loadModel($id), ));`, should I place it here?

Answer (score 6):

here is a good solution to use CDN and offline scripts

I use this code in every application I build, so you can use this in any app.

Included Scripts:

- main.css
- main.js
- jQuery
- jQuery / CD
- Bootstrap 3.1
- Bootstrap 3.1 / CDN
- Fancybox 2
- Fancybox 2 / CDN
- FontAwesome 4
- FontAwesome 4 / CDN
- Google Analytics Script

**STEP1:**

put this code in config/main.php

```
        'params'=>array(
            'cdn'=>true, // or false
...
```

**STEP2:**

create resoreses folder in root app folder and put your script there

```
res/
--js
--css
--img
--lib
--style
..
```

**STEP3:**

put this code in components/controller.php

```
public function registerDefaults() 
{
    $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;

    if (Yii::app()->params['cdn']){
        $cs->scriptMap = array(
            'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js',
            'jquery.min.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js',
        );
        $cs->packages = array(
            'bootstrap' => array(
                'basePath' => 'application.res',
                'baseUrl' => '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/',
                'js' => array('js/bootstrap.min.js'),
                'css' => array('css/bootstrap.min.css'),
                'depends' => array('jquery')
            ),
        );
    } else {
        $cs->packages = array(
            'bootstrap' => array(
                'basePath' => 'application.res',
                'baseUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/lib/bootstrap/',
                'js' => array('js/bootstrap.js'),
                'css' => array('css/bootstrap.css'),
                'depends' => array('jquery')
            ),
        );
    }

    $cs->registerPackage('bootstrap');

    $cs->registerCSSFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/style/main.css');
    $cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/js/main.js');
}

public function registerFancybox($buttons = false, $thumbs = false) 
{
    $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;

    $cs->packages = array(
        'fancybox' => array(
            'basePath' => 'application.res',
            'baseUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/lib/fancybox/',
            'js' => array('lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js', 'source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js'),
            'css' => array('source/jquery.fancybox.css'),
            'depends' => array('jquery')
        ),
        'fancybox-buttons' => array(
            'basePath' => 'application.res',
            'baseUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/lib/fancybox/source/helpers/',
            'js' => array('jquery.fancybox-buttons.js'),
            'css' => array('jquery.fancybox-buttons.css'),
        ),
        'fancybox-thumbs' => array(
            'basePath' => 'application.res',
            'baseUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/lib/fancybox/source/helpers/',
            'js' => array('jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js'),
            'css' => array('jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css'),
        )
    );

    $cs->registerPackage('fancybox');
    if ($buttons)
        $cs->registerPackage('fancybox-buttons');
    if ($thumbs)
        $cs->registerPackage('fancybox-thumbs');
}

public function registerFontAwesome(){

    $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;

    if (Yii::app()->params['cdn']):
        $cs->packages = array(
            'fontAwesome' => array(
                'basePath' => 'application.res',
                'baseUrl' => '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/',
                'css' => array('css/font-awesome.min.css'),
            )
        );
    else:
        $cs->packages = array(
            'fontAwesome' => array(
                'basePath' => 'application.res',
                'baseUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/res/lib/font-awesome/',
                'css' => array('/css/font-awesome.min.css'),
            )
        );
    endif;

    $cs->registerPackage('fontAwesome');
}

public function registerGoogleAnalytics()
{
    if($this->config('settings_google_analytics_id')){
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('GA',"
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', '".Yii::app()->params['cdn']."', '{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        ");
    }
}
```

**STEP4:**

call the functions like this in //layouts/main.php

```
Yii::app()->getController()->registerDefaults();
Yii::app()->getController()->registerFontAwesome();
Yii::app()->getController()->registerGoogleAnalytics();
```

Comment: am stuck on the best approach when using partial render. Am having my JS Files conflicting. Which is the best approach for this

Comment: Nice Solution. i will try it in my Application

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you want to add module assets both CSS and JS, you can use the following logic. See how you need to indicate the correct path to [getPathOfAlias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#getPathOfAlias-detail):

```
public static function register($file)
{
    $url = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(
    Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.modules.shop.assets.css'));

    $path = $url . '/' . $file;
    if(strpos($file, 'js') !== false)
        return Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($path);
    else if(strpos($file, 'css') !== false)
        return Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($path);

    return $path;
}
```

The above code has been taken from GPLed Yii based [Webshop](http://code.google.com/p/yii-shop/source/browse/trunk/models/Shop.php?spec=svn15&r=15) app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add scripts from controller action. Just add this line in an action method then that script will apear only in that view:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/js/custom.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

where POS_HEAD tell framework to put script in head section

Answer (score 1):

In Yii framework, You can include js and css using below method.

**Including CSS:**

```
{Yii::app()->request->baseUrl}/css/styles.css
```

**Including JS:**

```
{Yii::app()->request->baseUrl}/js/script.js
```

**Including Image:**

```
{Yii::app()->request->baseUrl}/images/logo.jpg
```

**Note:** By using layout concept in yii, You can add css and js instead of specifying in view template.

Answer (score 0):

> Add the CSS and JS in The Layout Folder.Access anywhere in the project

```
  <!--// Stylesheets //-->
    <?php
        $themepath=Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery");
    ?>

        <link href="<?php echo $themepath."/css/custom.css"; ?>" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />


<!--// Javascript //-->
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery"); ?>
</script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $themepath; ?>/js/video.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="/news/js/popup.js"></script>
```

link must input over the first php tag in the view pag

Answer (score 0):

**Using bootstrap extension**

my css file: *themes/bootstrap/css/style.css*

my js file: *root/js/script.js*

at *theme/bootstrap/views/layouts/main.php*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was also an easy way to add script and css in main.php

```
<script src="<?=Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?=Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Theme then you can the below Syntax**

```
Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl
```

include CSS File :

```
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

Include JS File

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

**If you are not using theme**

```
Yii::app()->request->baseUrl
```

Use Like this

```
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- In Yii Assets are declared in engine/assets/Appassets.php This make
  more easier to manage all your css and js files
  [image]