# yii and jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, yii

I am having problem with `Yii` and `jQuery` mobile. The problem is that `jQuery` mobile only use js files from `rel="external"` link, that are inside div with `data-role="page"`. `Yii` generates active form js at the end of div or in the header

I  tried to put

```
<script src='lala/js.js' type = "text/javascipt"></script>
```

and I could bind the `js`  and `css` with :

js.js:

```
$('div').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, ui){
$("head").append("<link>");
    css = $("head").children(":last");
    css.attr({
      rel:  "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: "/site/css/mobile/mobile.css"
    });
     $.getScript("/site/js/fancyForm_qe.js", function(){
         //some other stuff
     );
     });
   $('.successMessage').hide();
});
```

the problem is that I want to use `Yii` functions to add css and js. 
Any solutions?

Comment: Did you try the Yii functions ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998449/include-css-javascript-file-in-yii-framework )? Not sure why you couldn't make those work.

Comment: so, that didnt worked. I thing i use the html that jquery mobile get via ajax, and parse it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem is that jquery mobile does not include anything that's returned outside the page div.

Workaround is to use registerScript etc as you usually would, then $markup = $this->render('view,$params,true,true); You can then echo the complete markup (with script) inside your jquery mobile page.

PS: There are some changes going on in JQuery Mobile that removes the requirement to wrap pages  with a div data-role=page. Beta2 has this, but it seems like it's bugged.

Comment: Tnx, it led me to right direction:

`$markup = '';
Yii::app()->clientScript->render($markup);
echo($markup);`