# Yii - External JS files Inlclude , registerScriptFile and publish

Tags: yii

I am using YII framework for my web application . I have a question on registering external Java script file.

Could some one please help me ?

1. What is the best location to copy Java script file ( which folder )
2. I do see there are two ways to register that external Java script
   file

   **First approach**

   ```
    $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
    $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
    $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
   ```

   **Second approch**

   ```
    $cs=Yii::app()->getClientScript();
    $cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish('path/to/js'));
    $cs->registerScript('id', 'your js here');
   ```

In the first approach I am directly registering with  registerScriptFile and passing the java script file

In the second approach I am registering and publishing the script . That means it copies to assets folders. ( Please correct me If I am wrong )
and then what does the last step does, What is `id` and again `java script file` . (`$cs->registerScript('id', 'your js here');`)

In my case I am accessing it from one of the views , so in the second approach since it gets published to the asset folder  , if 10 clients calls the file does it published 10 times ( since I am accessing it from the  view file )

I am bit confused .

Thanks for your answer

Regards

Kiran

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include CSS,javascript file in Yii Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998449/include-css-javascript-file-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yii Assets folder is generally used by Widgets and Yii's internal components like Gridview. You don't need to store or publish your external JS or CSS files to assets folder.

Secondly if the files already exist in assets folder `getAssetManager()->publish('path/to/js')` will not copy it againg.

and last you don't need to instantiate CClientScript class, you can call it directly as

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/file.js'
);
```

or if you are using themes

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/js/file.js'
);
```

Comment: He is not -instantiating- the CClientScript class.

Answer (score 2):

In common case the best way is to put your JS files into web_root/js and to use `$cs->registerScriptFile`. AssetManager convenient to use in widgets. You can put your JS files into protected folder, and publish them to the assets folder when it's needed. If you'll call `publish()` method 10 times, it should publish your files only ones. If you set `$forceCopy` parameter to `true` (default is `false`), then it whould copy 10 times, but in the same dir.

Comment: Thank You Oleg for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered already - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19210733/2670583
See more [CClientScript for Yii](http://yii.codexamples.com/v1.1/CClientScript/)