# How to add JavaScript for a specific controller and action in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am working with an application using Yii. I need to add a JavaScript file  for a specific controller and action.  What is not necessary to load or add will go in another controller and action.  How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933024/yii-external-js-files-inlclude-registerscriptfile-and-publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your javascript in a layout or theme and add if you're in right controller.

You can find out your controller name like:
[Getting Current Controller ID in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582237/getting-current-controller-id-in-yii)

and register your javascript if you're in this controller, like @Telvin Nguyen said:
[Yii - External JS files Inlclude , registerScriptFile and publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933024/yii-external-js-files-inlclude-registerscriptfile-and-publish)