# Disabling javascript in Yii

Tags: javascript, yii

Is it possible to disable js loading manually in Yii?
I know Yii loads automatically scripts if are required. I want to disable them for debugging. 
I was looking in the config.main but in vain.

anyone ?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

In your config.main file, describe this as component.

```
'clientScript' =>array('scriptMap'=> array(
                'jquery.js'=>false,
                'jquery.ba-bbq.js'=>false,
                'jquery.yiilistview.js'=>false
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config file main.php in components array:

```
'clientScript' => array('scriptMap' => array('jquery.js' => false, )),
```

Exclude scripts which you dont need  or load your scripts.
[Include CSS,javascript file in Yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998449/include-css-javascript-file-in-yii-framework)