# Use jQuery plugin tablesorter in Yii view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, tablesorter

I’m trying to include the **jQuery plugin** [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) in my **Yii view** for “turning a standard HTML table with THEAD and TBODY tags into a sortable table without page refreshes”.

I am aware that CGridView would be a more elegant version to do this in Yii but I am mainly interested in getting the jQuery plugin to work.
As of now, the table is not sortable although other jQuery functions (e.g., a pop-up window or a toggle button) work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
This is my view:

```
<?php 
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'); 

    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('buttonscript',"
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('p').slideToggle();
    });
    ",CClientScript::POS_READY);

    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('/jquery.tablesorter.js');

    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('tablescript',"
        $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                $('#myTable1').tablesorter(); 
            } 
        ); 
    ",CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>

<?php
    echo "<p id='paragraph1'>This is a paragraph.</p>";
    echo "<button id='button1'>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element</button>";

    echo "<table id='myTable1' class='tablesorter'> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Last Name</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
        </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>John</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Jones</td> 
            <td>Martha</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Noble</td> 
            <td>Donna</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>Mickey</td> 
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>";
?>
```

**Edit:** Must be a path problem. When I hotlink directly to jquery.tablesorter.js, it works fine. Question can be closed.

Comment: What does the developer console of your browser say?

Comment: It says "TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function". I think the script isn't included in the right way.

Comment: The `'/'` in `/jquery.tablesorter.js` directs to your web root. Use `Yii::app()->baseUrl`

Comment: Shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055764/980615